# URL amigável, como fazer funcionar com HTACCESS

Tags: php, htaccess, apache

Criei algumas regras em meu arquivo `.htaccess` para formatar a visualização da *URL*, mas estou tendo dificuldade em passar o parâmetro para a página que mostra os produtos e mostrar a *URL Amigável* formatada, o código está assim:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^Pagina-Inicial\/?$ index.php?acessando=home [L]
RewriteRule ^institucional\/?$ index.php?acessando=institucional [L]
RewriteRule ^promocoes\/?$ index.php?acessando=promocoes [L]
RewriteRule ^lojas\/?$ index.php?acessando=lojas [L]
RewriteRule ^lojas\/?$ index.php?acessando=loja [L]
RewriteRule ^contato\/?$ index.php?acessando=contato [L]
RewriteRule ^trabalhe\/?$ index.php?acessando=trabalhe [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z,0-9,A-Z,_-]+)$ /produtos.php?dep=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-z,0-9,A-Z,_-]+)\/([a-z,0-9,A-Z,_-]+)$ /produtos.php?dep=$1&sup=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-z,0-9,A-Z,_-]+)\/([a-z,0-9,A-Z,_-]+)\/([a-z,0-9,A-Z,_-]+)$ /detalhes.php?produto=$1&dep=$2&sub=$3
```

Por exemplo, quando o cliente clicar em COZINHA redireciona para a página **produtos.php** passando o parâmetro e mostrando na *URL* algo assim, fiz uma edição para tentar deixar mais claro.

Quando o usuário clicar no menu principal, hoje está assim:

```
http://moveissaobento.com.br/msb/produtos.php?dep=1
http://moveissaobento.com.br/msb/produtos.php?dep=2
http://moveissaobento.com.br/msb/produtos.php?dep=3
```

Gostaria de deixar assim:

```
http://moveissaobento.com.br/msb/COZINHA
http://moveissaobento.com.br/msb/DORMITORIO
http://moveissaobento.com.br/msb/SALA-DE-JANTAR
```

Quando o usuário clicar no submenu, hoje está assim:

```
http://moveissaobento.com.br/msb/produtos.php?dep=1&sub=4
http://moveissaobento.com.br/msb/produtos.php?dep=2&sub=15
http://moveissaobento.com.br/msb/produtos.php?dep=3&sub=34
```

Gostaria de deixar assim:

```
http://moveissaobento.com.br/msb/COZINHA/AMBIENTE-MESA-C/-BANQUETAS
http://moveissaobento.com.br/msb/COZINHA/AMBIENTE-MESA-C/-CADEIRAS
```

Não sei exatamente como fazer para mostrar a *URL* na forma amigável.

Comment: No seu PHP você já tem algum código para pegar o ID do item (categoria, subcategoria e produto) através do nome passado?

Comment: Olá @AndréRibeiro, tenho o código que recebe o id do departamento, subdepartamento e produto mas não da forma como você disse, pelo nome passado.

Comment: Um outra dúvida: você realmente precisa passar o id do departamento e subdepartamento para abrir a página do produto? Porque se realmente precisar você vai ter que passar o id dos dois na URL de algum modo.

Comment: Sim @AndréRibeiro, preciso passar esses id´s, da forma como está e pelo que li em alguns artigos até tem como, mas eu não consegui.

Comment: essa barra vai dar conflito na regra: AMBIENTE-MESA-C`/`-CADEIRAS, tem que tratar isso para: AMBIENTE-MESA-COM-CADEIRAS.

Comment: Relacionado: [URL amigável utilizando HTACCESS](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75963/url-amig%C3%A1vel-utilizando-htaccess)

Comment: @KaduAmaral, valeu pelo excelente link, me ajudou bastante.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A flag **QSA**, informa que somente **QUERY_STRING** poderá acessá-las.
A flag **NC** (nocase), é para ignorar *case sensitive* (caixa alta/baixa).
A flag **L** (last) é um sinalizador para indicar que a regra atual deve ser aplicada imediatamente, sem considerar outras regras (ou seja, ela se torna independente).

A flag **R** (redirect) provoca um redirecionamento HTTP (quando houver o domínio ou servidor escrito na URL do navegador).

Para iniciar uma regra use: `^` , para terminar a regra use: `$`, utilize expressões regulares para tratar os dados que serão fornecidos na URL do navegador para interpretar a saída da url do sistema.

Para cada conjunto de regras, exemplo `(regra1)(regra2)(regran...)` na frente da regra coloque o endereço do sistema: `sua_pagina.php?data1=$1&data2=$2&data3=$...`, no link do sistema, coloque a regra formatada, que ela irá ler a página, e depois da URL, coloque as flags listadas dentro de colchetes `[]`, há várias flags, que pode ser [**conferida aqui**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html).

Isso permite que o *Google* ou demais buscadores indexem melhor seu site.
Para saber mais, acesse a [**documentação do Apache**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

```
 RewriteEngine On
    #aqui criamos uma condição para que os arquivos sejam ignorados nas regras abaixo
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  #aqui criamos uma condição para que diretórios sejam ignorados nas regras abaixo
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    #aqui definimos onde começa a base das regras
    #vamos supor que fosse um subdiretório, como por exemplo: /vs1/
    RewriteBase /
    #aqui ignoramos o uso de barra no final
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\/?$ $1 [R,L]

    #fix rules 
    RewriteRule ^pagina-inicial$ index.php?acessando=home [QSA,L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^institucional$ index.php?acessando=institucional [QSA,L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^promocoes$ index.php?acessando=promocoes [QSA,L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^lojas$ index.php?acessando=lojas [QSA,L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^loja$ index.php?acessando=loja [QSA,L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^contato$ index.php?acessando=contato [QSA,L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^trabalhe$ index.php?acessando=trabalhe [QSA,L,NC]

    #dinamic rules
    RewriteRule ^msb\/([0-9A-z_-]+)$ msb/produtos.php?dep=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^msb\/([0-9A-z_-]+)\/([0-9A-z_-]+)$ msb/produtos.php?dep=$1&produto=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^msb\/([0-9A-z_-]+)\/([0-9A-z_-]+)\/([0-9A-z_-]+)$ msb/detalhes.php?produto=$1&dep=$2&sub=$3 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Aqui tem uma sugestão de site para que você personalize suas regras:
    **http://regexr.com/**

Comment: Será que pode explicar o porquê? Assim beneficia quem não sabe muito sobre o assunto. Mais que o autor da pergunta, a idéia é que as respostas ajudem visitantes futuros com dúvidas iguais ou parecidas. Valeu!

Comment: @brasofilo, eu dei uma pequena explicação, espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Com certeza, já aprendi um par de coisas com sua explicação. Obrigado!

Answer (score 5):

Não acho muito interessante escrever tuas regras assim

```
RewriteRule ^Pagina-Inicial\/?$ index.php?acessando=home
```

olhando pelo lado de um sistema pequeno não parece ser um problema mas se tu tem um sistema muito grande vai haver a necessidade de tu escrever muitas regras, ai deixa de ser interessante, mas se tu receber a query da url completa tu pode tratar ela no PHP e direcionar da forma que tu quiser, um exemplo de htaccess que uso é esse

```
# compressão básica
<IfModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js)$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</IfModule>
# Proteger os arquivos e diretórios
<FilesMatch "(\.(engine|inc|info|install|module|profile|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)? |xtmpl)|code-style\.pl|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$">
Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>
# Não mostrar listagens de diretório
Options -Indexes
# Regras básicas de reescrita, parar desnecessários bot PERL, bloquear diretórios de subversão
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?\.svn/ - [F,L]
ErrorDocument 403 "Acesso proibido"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.*
RewriteRule .* – [F,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\/]+)$ index.php?$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

por exemplo se a requisição for assim "http://example.com/news/economy"
minha regra:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\/]+)$ index.php?$1 [NC,L]
```

vai receber "news/economy" pois meu regex permite letras, números e a barra, sendo assim posso tratar minhas urls no código e caso alguma que o usuário digite e não tenha no meu sistema eu já redireciono para uma página 404. espero ter ajudado. ;)

Comment: Bingo ! Perfeito essa regex que permite a barra !

Comment: E seu eu precisar adicionar o hífen nessa expressão como seria?

Comment: denis pode utilizar `[A-Za-z0-9\-\/]`, creio que ficaria algo assim, qualquer coisa você pode testar regex no site regexr.com e fazer um da forma que tu achar melhor, até usando "wildcards" para aceitar qualquer caracter.