# URL amigável utilizando HTACCESS

Tags: php, htaccess

Tenho o seguinte link: `dominio.com/?p=filmes_v&m=tt081692`
Meu `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteRule ^film/?$ index.php?p=filmes [NC,L]
  RewriteRule ^film/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?p=filmes_v&?m=$2 [NC]
</IfModule>
```

Meu objetivo é: `dominio.com/film/tt081692`

Mas não consigo colocar a variável `$m` do link no `.htaccess`

Tenho outro problema:

```
dominio.com/film  -> O site fica certo

dominio.com/film/ -> O CSS não é carregado
```

Comment: Troque a linha: `RewriteRule ^film/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?p=filmes_v&?m=$1 [NC]`, sobre o CSS seria melhor postar como está fazendo.

Comment: Obrigado @PapaCharlie, o $2 foi distração minha mesmo.

Comment: @KaduAmaral, esse era o meu problema, consegui resolver, obrigado.

Comment: Já agora, o problema do CSS a partir disto acho que consigo resolver :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Resolução

Remova o `?` antes do `m` e use variável `$1`:

```
RewriteRule ^film/([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ index.php?p=filmes_v&m=$1 [NC]
```

O `htaccess` ficará da seguinte forma:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteRule ^film/?$ index.php?p=filmes [NC,L]
  RewriteRule ^film/([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ index.php?p=filmes_v&m=$1 [NC]
</IfModule>
```

<sub>Note que dentro de `[]` em expressões regulares é recomendado escapar `-`, pois os mesmos são utilizados na sintaxe da expressão, como exemplo `[a-z]` que indica de `a` até `z`. — @GuilhermeNascimento</sub>

### Links e Scripts

Utilizando URL amigável você <del>precisa</del> pode utilizar caminhos absolutos ou apenas referenciar os arquivos indicando uma `/` no início do caminho:

```
<link href="http://meudominio.com/css/meucss.css">
<!-- ou -->
<link href="/css/meucss.css">

<a href="http://meudominio.com/contato">
<!-- ou -->
<a href="/contato">

<script src="http://meudominio.com/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- ou -->
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

#### Caminhos Relativos

**Atenção:** Caminhos relativos **tem** que ser iniciado com `/` que indica raiz do site, pois caso a página atual tenha um endereço semelhante a `http://meudominio.com/contato` e o usuário clicar em um link `<a href="sobre">Sobre</a>` ele acabará no endereço `http://meudominio.com/contato/sobre`.

Um recurso muito interessante pra utilizar com caminhos relativos é o `RewriteBase`. Por exemplo imagine que você tenha um blog e ele esta estruturado mais ou menos assim no servidor:

```
/root
| - /www
|   | - /blog
|       | - /css
|       | - /js
```

E a URL pra acessar esse blog é `http://meusite.com/blog/` então em todo o seu código você vai ter que referenciar seus *scripts* e *links* utilizando a URL semi-relativa `/blog/`.

```
<link href="/blog/css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="/blog/js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<a href="/blog/sobre">Sobre</a>
```

Mas se no `htaccess` do *Blog* for definido o `RewriteBase` para `blog`, não precisará mais do `/blog/` na URL:

```
RewriteBase /blog/
```

E suas URLs podem ficar:

```
<link href="/css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="/js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<a href="/sobre">Sobre</a>
```

E assim se em algum momento você resolver alterar o endereço `http://meusite.com/blog/` para `http://blog.meusite.com` só precisará alterar o `RewriteBase` para `/` ou remove-lo:

```
RewriteBase /
```

Assim não precisará alterar todos os *links* removendo o tal `/blog` das URLs. :)

<sub>Você também pode ter esse recurso através da [tag `base`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp). Mas prefiro no `htaccess`.</sub>

### Outros meios

Uma forma bastante interessante de se fazer URLs amigáveis é a forma que eu chamo de *URLs Amigáveis Dinâmicas*, a implementação seria assim:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?uri=$1
</IfModule>
```

Dessa forma você pode tratar a URI no PHP receber quantas variáveis quiser, exemplo:

```
$tmp = !empty($_GET['uri']) ? $_GET['uri'] : 'home'; // Página padrão home

$uri = explode('/', $tmp);

$vars = Array();

if (count($uri) > 1){
    $key = 'page';
    foreach ($uri as $val) {
        if (is_null($key))
            $key = $val;
        else {
            $vars[$key] = $val;
            $key = NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

No exemplo anterior, você pode enviar a URL `http://meudominio/catalogo/categoria/eletrodomestico/preco/100~500/voltagem/220` e você teria a seguinte estrutura na variável `$vars`:

```
page        => catalogo
categoria   => eletrodomestico
preco       => 100~500
voltagem    => 220
```

Assim o primeiro argumento sempre é a página e os seguintes são qualquer parâmetro que desejar, em qualquer ordem e sempre devem ser
enviados em dupla `chave/valor`. Essa forma é bastante útil para fazer filtros.

#### Modelo MVC

Utilizando esse conceito fica simples aplicar um modelo MVC que seria:

```
controller/action/demais/parametros
```

Como por exemplo:

```
$tmp = !empty($_GET['uri']) ? $_GET['uri'] : 'home'; // Página padrão home

$uri = explode('/', $tmp);

$vars = Array(
    // Controller `index` caso não tenha parâmetros na URI, caso tenha armaza e remove-o da URI
    'controller'   => (count($uri) > 0 ? array_shift($uri) : 'index'),
    // Action `index` caso não tenha parâemtros na URI
    'action'       => (count($uri) > 0 ? array_shift($uri) : 'index'),
    // Demais parâmetros
    'params'       => Array()
);

$key = NULL;
if (count($uri) > 1){
    foreach ($uri as $val) {
        if (is_null($key))
            $key = $val;
        else {
            $vars['params'][$key] = $val;
            $key = NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

Assim acessando a URL:

```
www.meudominio.com/sobre/empresa/page/3
```

Teremos o seguinte resultado:

```
$vars = Array(
    'controller' => 'sobre',
    'action'     => 'empresa',
    'params'     => Array(
        'page' => '3'
    )
);
```

#### [Outro Exemplo para MVC](https://github.com/KaduAmaral/Base/blob/e22d6100633a73eaca9d8aa3176a6331da2fcb0c/base/core/request.class.php#L48)

Comment: Não existe outra maneira?

Comment: Adicione no teu htaccess `RewriteBase /`, veja se funciona, no teste que fiz não funcionou @xdam98.

Comment: Não, não funcionou @KaduAmaral

Comment: De fato não é o que eu pensava. Aqui tem uma [resposta em inglês sobre seu uso](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704102/how-does-rewritebase-work-in-htaccess). Realmente precisa utilizar URL Absoluta, eu geralmente crio uma constante `define('SITE', 'http://meusite/');` com o endereço e uso nas referencias: `href="<?=SITE?>css/meucss.css"` @xdam98

Comment: Ok, obrigado pela dica :) Por enquanto irei fazer como disse. Entretanto irei estudar mais sobre .htaccess

Comment: Beleza, depois vou complementar essa resposta. @xdam98

Comment: Só uma dica, ao invés de usar `<a href="http://meudominio.com/contato">` e `<a href="http://meudominio.com/level1/level2">` prefira `<a href="/contato">` e `<a href="/level1/level2">`, assim evitará dificuldades acaso use https ou "domínios espelhos", pois com o url inteiro pode acabar direcionando pra uma página inexistente. @xdam98

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento discordo, caso ele esteja na página `http://meudominio.com/contato` e clicar no link `/level1/level2` ele provavelmente cairá no endereço `http://meudominio.com/contato/level1/leve2`. Para resolver o problema que você indicou, basta tirar o `http:` e deixar `<a href="//meudominio.com/contato">`.

Comment: Não @KaduAmaral a `/` de `href="/level1/level2"` no começo leva a "raiz", desculpe mas acho que você se confundiu. O problema só ocorreria se fosse `href="level1/level2"` sem a barra no começo.

Comment: É verdade @GuilhermeNascimento, não prestei bem atenção, o mesmo funciona para arquivos CSS e Javascript, desde que iniciado com `/` indicando a raiz do site funciona normalmente.

Comment: @KaduAmaral eu só não recomendei pro CSS e JS porque geralmente é recomendável um servidor CDN a parte acaso você divida estes arquivos estáticos com vários domínios, por exemplo múltiplos portais de noticias que podem usar a mesma tecnologia, mas isto é um pouco relativo a cada projeto e por isto não o mencionei e nem recomendo mencionar.

Comment: Vale também comentar ao autor que ao invés de usar `^film/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$` use `^film/([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$`, não sei se isto faz diferença no apache, mas em RegEx devemos "escapar" o `-` dentro de `[...]`

Comment: Sim @GuilhermeNascimento, mas como a pergunta é sobre URL Amigável não acho necessário gastar explicações com CDN que "não tem" muito a ver com o tópico.

Comment: @KaduAmaral Mas foi exatamente o que eu disse sobre o CDN: *"isto é um pouco relativo a cada projeto e por isto não o mencionei e nem recomendo mencionar."*, como eu disse, aquilo é apenas uma justificativa do porque não mencionei o CDN, pois é pouco relativo, tanto pra pergunta quanto para o projeto, já que pode variar.

Comment: kkkk não me irritei o.0 -- exagero seu, eu só expliquei :p

Comment: @KaduAmaral quando passamos todas as urls pelo **index.php** temos que fazer um script pra receber os **gets** e mandar pro destino em cima das especificações dos **gets**

Comment: Exatamente @MarcosVinicius, na resposta eu coloquei apenas o _script_ que pega os _gets_, mas depois disso vem a parte onde chama-se o código desejado, seja ele a execução de um _controller_ e _action_ ou um _require_ de um arquivo, depende da estrutura de cada projeto.

Comment: A respeito de seu css não carregar basta utilizar a tag <base href="seuenderecocompleto"> no index de seu projeto.

Comment: @DeveloperWebSistem... o atributo `RewriteBase /blog/` tem a mesma função.

Comment: @KaduAmaral Tentei e não obtive resultado: RewriteBase /urlAmigavel/