# Ajuda na criação do arquivo .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, htaccess

Amigos, boa tarde.
Estou tentando a dias criar um .htaccess bacana, porém estamos com algumas dificuldades.

Seguem exemplos do que necessito, lembrando que tudo precisa estar na mesma URL.

1) Sempre que o usuário for acessar o web site quero que adicione um "/home/" no fim da URL.

```
Antes: http://app.meusite.com/ 

Depois: http://app.meusite.com/home/
```

2) Quero que todas as URL sejam removidas o ".php".

```
Antes: http://app.meusite.com/login.php

Depois: http://app.meusite.com/login/
```

3) Quero que todas as URLs que sejam da seguinte forma:

Antes:

```
http://app.meusite.com/usuario-adicionar.php

http://app.meusite.com/usuario-editar.php

http://app.meusite.com/usuario-excluir.php
```

Depois:

```
http://app.meusite.com/usuario/adicionar/

http://app.meusite.com/usuario/editar/

http://app.meusite.com/usuario/excluir/
```

Só tem uma observação a ser levada em consideranção...

Pelo fato de todo o site ser multi-idiomas, preciso que todas as página aceitem o parâmetro get que será LANG=IDIOMA (Ex.: lang=en_US)

Então todas as URLS acima, devem aceitar o paramento de GET também, e gostaria que ficasse da seguinte forma:

```
http://app.meusite.com/index.php?lang=en_US
http://app.meusite.com/home/en_US/

http://app.meusite.com/login.php?lang=en_US
http://app.meusite.com/login/en_US/

http://app.meusite.com/usuario-adicionar.php?lang=en_US
http://app.meusite.com/usuario/adicionar/en_US/

http://app.meusite.com/usuario-editar.php?lang=en_US
http://app.meusite.com/usuario/editar/en_US/

http://app.meusite.com/usuario-excluir.php?lang=en_US
http://app.meusite.com/usuario/excluir/en_US/
```

**Como estou fazendo:**

```
Options -MultiViews
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$

RewriteRule ^home\/?(.*)\/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\/?(.*)\/?$ $1.php?lang=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\/([^/]*)\/([^/]*)\/?$ $1-$2.php?lang=$3 [L]
```

Espero que dê para compreender minha dúvida.

Desde já, muito obrigado a todos.

Abraço!

Comment: Pergunta relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75963/url-amig%C3%A1vel-utilizando-htaccess/75970#75970

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar somente esse htaccess =

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

E tratar toda a logica nessa index.php, usando o comando =

```
$url = explode("/", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
```

Acessa uma url e da um print na variavel $url que você vai entender melhor, ai dentro dos ifs que você vai fazer dentro de cada url, você da um include na pagina que vai ser aberta.

Outra forma de se fazer é fazendo uma regra htaccess para cada url usando expressões regulares.