# Problema com formulário (método GET) e URL Amigável

Tags: php, htaccess, get

Estou com um problema ao enviar um form, pois estou usando um esquema que muda as paginas conforme o `GET['page']`, e usei a url amigável para tirar todo aquele código para deixar somente o nome da pagina, por exemplo `localhost?page=inicio`, agora está `localhost/inicio`.

Mas estou com um problema nisso pois quando preciso enviar mais um `get`, o php não consegue pegar, pois o form envia o "`?`" na frente do get, sendo que o php so vai pegar se o html enviar "`&`" antes do nome do GET

Exemplo de como está acontecendo: `localhost/inicio?b=pedro`, isso quer dizer `localhost?page=inicio?b=pedro`

Como fazer para ficar assim `localhost/inicio&b=pedro`, que irá ficar assim sem a url amigável `localhost?page=inicio&b=pedro`.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ index.php?page=$1


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: Você fez a URL amigável com HTACCESS certo? Pode postar o código dele? Use o link [editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/77499/edit) logo abaixo da sua pergunta para adicionar essas informações.

Comment: Prontinho ^^ !!!

Comment: Romario, você está disposto a alterar a regra do seu formulário com jQuery/Javascript? Dê uma olhada nessa resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/75970/8493 se estiver, poste o código do seu formulário (e códigos javascript já utilizados se houver).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta adicionar a *flag* `[QSA]` (*QueryString Append*):

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [QSA]
```

<sub>[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6656450/3497987)</sub>

Também pode simplificar as duas primeiras regras para apenas uma:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

O `?` após um carácter na expressão regular, significa que ele é facultativo, pode ou não have-lo.

Comment: Deu certo cara tu é fera em! onde tem material para que eu possa estar estudando sobre esses itens? O que é QSA?o que ele faz?

Comment: Eu coloquei ali abaixo do código o link [fonte](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6656450/3497987) @RomarioPires