# URL amigável com Nginx

Tags: php, nginx, url-amigável

Gostaria de uma ajuda de vocês pois não cheguei no resultado esperado.

Estou tentando criar uma URL amigável como abaixo:

URL atual:

```
meusite.com.br/artista.php?id_artista=1
```

URL nova:

```
meusite.com.br/nome-do-artista
```

Sendo que depois terei:

```
meusite.com.br/nome-do-artista/discografia
meusite.com.br/nome-do-artista/musicas
meusite.com.br/nome-do-artista/informacoes
```

O máximo que consegui foi deixar a URL assim:

```
meusite.com.br/artista/nome-do-artista
```

Nginx

```
rewrite ^/artista/([a-z]+) /artista.php?artista=$1 last;
```

Comment: Essa regra está reescrevendo essa URL `meusite.com.br/artista/nome-do-artista`, não é isso que está querendo? Nginx é um equivalente ao Apache?

Comment: @KaduAmaral exatamente, o Nginx é similar ao Apache. Da forma que está essa regra, funciona perfeitamente  para o caso `meusite.com.br/artista/joao`, mas eu gostaria de alterar para `meusite.com.br/joao`

Comment: Então é só tirar a parte `/artista/` da regra @Ricardo. ;)

Comment: Você deve especificar o caminho dos CSS desde a base da URL usando a barra `/`, exemplo `/css/meucss.css` ou usando a URL absoluta `meusite.com.br/css/meucss.css`. [Para mais detalhes dê uma lida nos comentários dessa resposta.](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/75970/8493)

Comment: @KaduAmaral, valeu! Vou testar aqui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Resolução:

A sua regra:

```
rewrite ^/artista/([a-z]+) /artista.php?artista=$1 last;
```

Está redirecionando a URL:

```
meusite.com.br/artista/nomedoartista
```

Para remover o trecho `/artista/` da URL, basta remover o mesmo da regra

```
rewrite ^([a-z]+) /artista.php?artista=$1 last;
```

Uma outra observação na sua regra, mais especificamente na expressão regular é que `[a-z]` busca apenas letras de `a` à `z`. (Não tenho certeza também se é *case sensitive*)

Na documentação os exemplos usam `(.*)` que significa qualquer carácter, mas eu aconselho usar `[\w\-_]+` ou `[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+` que pega carácteres alfanuméricos (maiúsculos e minúsculos), números, traço (-) e *underscore* (_):

```
rewrite ^([\w\-_]+)/?$ /artista.php?artista=$1 last;
```

Obs.: O trecho `/?` significa que pode haver ou não uma barra `/` no final.

A regra para pegar as URLs com os demais parâmetros seria:

```
rewrite ^([\w\-_]+)/([\w\-_]+)/?$ /artista.php?artista=$1&info=$2 last;

//               $artista        $info
//meusite.com.br/nome-do-artista/discografia
//meusite.com.br/nome-do-artista/musicas
//meusite.com.br/nome-do-artista/informacoes
```

---

**Nota:** Nunca trabalhei com Ngnix, os exemplos postados aqui foram baseados apenas nas expressões regulares (que acredito ser as mesmas para Apache mod_rewrite e Ngnix), não validei, nem testei a sintaxe do módulo de *rewrite* do Ngnix.

---

#### Relacionados

[URL amigável utilizando HTACCESS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75963/url-amig%C3%A1vel-utilizando-htaccess/75970#75970)

[Problema com formulário (método GET) e URL Amigável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/77499/problema-com-formul%C3%A1rio-m%C3%A9todo-get-e-url-amig%C3%A1vel/77527#77527)

Comment: mesmo colocando a URL absoluta do CSS ele ficou todo bagunçado. provavelmente porque o caminho é `www.meusite.com.br/images/...` será que ele entende que o `/images/` seja o nome de algum cantor?

Comment: É possível, no htaccess existem condições que verifica se a URL acessada é um arquivo. Fiz uma busca na web e encontrei essa condição do Ngnix `if (!-f $request_filename)`, coloque suas regras dentro dessa condição e verifique novamente. Outro teste é acessar o endereço dos arquivos CSS no browser e verificar o que aparece @Ricardo

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente com as regras dentro desse IF @Kadu. Valeu!

Comment: A unica coisa que não funcionou, é quando uso alguma coisa após o nome do cantor, tipo `www.meusite.com.br/joao/discografia`. Fiz assim: `rewrite ^([a-z]+)/discografia /discografia.php?artista=$1 last;`

Comment: @Ricardo use a flag `break` em vez da `last` e veja se funciona... [Fonte](http://serverfault.com/a/426167) -> [Wiki](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite)

Comment: Assim `rewrite ^([a-z]+)/discografia /discografia.php?artista=$1 break;`? Se for, ele abre a janela para download do arquivo..

Comment: @Ricardo testou sem flags?

Comment: não, vou testar amanhã e te falo!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27386/discussion-between-ricardo-and-kaduamaral).