# Como fazer requisições GET sem ter que usar ponto de interrogação na URL

Tags: php, url

Gostaria de saber como eu posso substituir os pontos de interrogação e ampersand da minha URL mas continuar podendo fazer requisições GET. Por exemplo:

eu quero que a url

```
exemplo.com/perfil.php?usuario=johndoe
```

vire

```
exemplo.com/perfil/usuario/johndoe
```

Mas de maneira que no perfil.php eu continue conseguindo fazer

```
$_GET['usuario'];
```

Pode parecer pedir muito, mas peço que por favor expliquem detalhadamente, pois eu não sou lá a melhor pessoa se tratando de programação :/ Obrigado

Comment: Ola @Bruno acho que essas perguntas podem te ajudar [Como posso simplificar os URLs para um site?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1326/3774), [URL amigável com Nginx](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82177/3774)

Comment: Pesquisa sobre url amigável e htaccess, isso resolve.

Comment: Sua pergunta é muito ampla, mas tente ler este artigo, pode ajudar http://blog.thiagobelem.net/aprendendo-urls-amigaveis

Answer (score -1):

Crie um arquivo chamado .htaccess e cole o seguinte código

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]`

Em seguida salve esse arquivo na raiz do seu site, muito importante, se você estiver fazendo seu site em localhost tem que ativar o mod_rewrite do Apache

Segundo passo é manipular a URL passada no .htaccess

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_GET['url'])){
    $url = $_GET['url'];//pega o valor da url
    $open_url = explode('/', $url);//separa a URL depois de cada barra (exemplo: www.meusite.com/artigo/novidades
}

if(isset($open_url[0])){
    $arquivo = $open_url[0];//dá um print_r($open_url) que você vai entender
}elseif(isset($open_url[1])){
    $post = $open_url[1];
}
```

Aqui você faz as verificações das páginas permitidas

```
$diretorio = "pasta";//nome do diretório onde as páginas tem que estar
$paginas = array('pagina1','pagina2');

if(isset($arquivo) && in_array($arquivo, $paginas)){
   include_once("$diretorio/$arquivo.php");
}else{
  include_once("$diretorio/home.php");
}
```

Desculpa se ficou confuso,respondi do celular, tá aí um sisteminha bem básico de URL AMIGAVEL