# URL amigavel, imagens não aparem mesmo colocando caminho absoluto

Tags: php, imagem, url-amigável

Estou enfrentando esse problema com minha URL amigavel, mesmo colocando o caminho absoluto ela não mostra as imagens.
Porém as imagens que estão em uma pasta no mesmo local do `.htacess` aparecem normalmente, as que não aparecem são as que estão no seguinte diretório `admin/imgsupload`.

Também já tentei utilizar outra configuração no htacess e a tag base, mas sem sucesso, lembrando que só está dando esse problema nas imagens que estão no diretorio `admin/imgsupload`, o que está na mesma pasta que o `.htacess` funciona normalmente.

Segue os códigos do meu htacess e de como estou colocando as imagens:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /projetolcj/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(jpg|gif|jpeg|png|js|css|swf|ico|txt|pdf|xml|woff)$
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) url.php
</IfModule>
```

Img:

```
<img src="/projetolcj/admin/<?php echo $linha["imagem"]; ?>" alt="parceiro" class=" thumbnail img-responsive">
```

Comment: possível duplicata de [URL amigável utilizando HTACCESS](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75963/url-amig%c3%a1vel-utilizando-htaccess)

Comment: Vinícios, as páginas funcionam normalmente? Tente utilizando os parâmetros `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` e `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` em vez dessa expressão regular.

Comment: Tentei dessa forma e não deu certo,sim todas as páginas funcionam normalmente...

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/53973/url-amig%C3%A1vel-como-fazer-funcionar-com-htaccess/86900#86900

Comment: Só que você está fazendo é totalmente o oposto: criou uma condicional para negar qualquer "arquivo" que contenham as extensões `(jpg|gif|jpeg|png|js|css|swf|ico|txt|pdf|xml|woff)`.

Comment: Já tentei mudar isso,e também não funcionou...

Answer (score 2):

Ponha isso no head do site:
`<base href="http://localhost/Sua_Pasta/">` se estiver trabalhando local ou
`<base href="http://seusite.com/">` se já estiver com eles na hospedagem

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que desta forma você vai liberar os arquivos que você precisa:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /projetolcj/
 #acessa as requisições abaixo
 #se for um arquivos vazio
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
 #ou se for um link de referência (simbólico)
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
 #ou se for um diretório
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule ^ - [L]
 RewriteRule ^(.*) url.php
</IfModule>
```

Mas se você deseja liberar somente estes arquivos da lista, então, faça assim:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /projetolcj/
  #ignora todas as regras abaixo quando for arquivo 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  #ignora todas as regras abaixo quando for diretório 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  #qualquer coisa que contenha as extensões abaixo não serão tratadas pelas regras a seguir, somente nesta condição
  RewriteCond $1 !^(\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.png|\.js|\.css|\.swf|\.ico|\.txt|\.pdf|\.xml|\.woff)
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]
  RewriteRule ^(.*) url.php
</IfModule>
```

Para editar as permissões no Linux:

Diretório:

```
user@host:/projeto/imagens$ sudo chmod 775 -R ./
```

Arquivos:

```
user@host:/projeto/imagens$ sudo chmod 664 ./
```

Para editar a permissão no Windows **[assista esse vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xdLblP2p4jg)**.

Comment: Tentei dessa forma,passou a dar erro 404.

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: http://gustavodutra.com/geek/como-usar-mod_rewrite-de-verdade

Comment: erro 404 é página não encontrada. Isso significa que o arquivo que você está tentando acessar não está na pasta, e não que ele foi negado.

Comment: Veja se sua pasta está com permissão 775 e se o arquivo está com permissão 664

Comment: Desculpa a ignorancia ivan,mas como faço para ver se minha pasta está com essa permissão?

Comment: É linux ou windows?

Comment: Windows,não sei se vem ao caso mas estou utilizando o wamp...

Comment: Eu mexo com Linux, e se sua questão é como dar permissão de escrita e leitura em pastas do windows, acho melhor você abrir uma outra pergunta para isso.

Comment: minha dica é faça testes: primeiro tente acessar o arquivo sem usar modo de reescrita primeiro. pega seu arquivo `.htaccess` renomeie para `_.htaccess` e tente abrir o arquivo direto na url.

Comment: Ok,grato mesmo assim,você me ajudou bastante.

Comment: Se não abrir o problema não está no `.htaccess`.

Comment: A maioria dos problemas que dão de reescrita é justamente quando todo o sistema é apontado para um arquivo index.php e ele não consegue encontrar as imagens, js, css, etc... o ideal é você colocar isso numa pasta pública (public). Fora da execução do seu sistema.

Comment: E nesta pasta pública, você tem que conceder acesso total de escrita.

Comment: Se você estiver utilizando algum framework em seu projeto, geralmente ele vem com uma configuração original que dá permissão para os arquivos no `.htaccess`, mas por ventura, se você estiver editando isso manualmente, é recomendável ter uma configuração funcional como base, se for seu seu caso, eu posso te passar um `.htaccess` que tem várias regras para isso.

Comment: Eu estou editando manualmente,se você puder me ajudar com isso eu agradeceria,percebi também que o meu upload de imagens não está conseguindo enviar a imagem para a pasta que deveria enviar...