# URL Amigável com Parâmetros Genéricos .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, htaccess, seo, url-amigável

Gostaria de montar uma `URL` amigável com parâmetros genéricos, ou seja, que receba qualquer parâmetro em qualquer quantidade ou arquivo.

Hoje montei o `.htaccess` para que o nome do arquivo vire a `URL`. Arquivo que estou utilizando:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ $1.php
    Options -Indexes

    ErrorDocument 404 /erro.php
</IfModule>
```

Exemplo da `URL` que gostaria:

> site.com.br/nome-do-arquivo/parametro-01/parametro-02/parametro-03/...

Caso alguém saiba montar, seria de muita ajuda.

Comment: Moises dê uma olhada nessa resposta e veja se é o que deseja: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/75970/8493

Comment: @KaduAmaral Não existe uma forma direta no `.htaccess`? Precisar tratar no `PHP` mesmo?

Comment: Sim @MoisesGama, o htaccess em sí não é pra programar, é apenas um arquivo de configuração. Você precisa tratar no PHP, o que eu não vejo nenhuma desvantagem.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer desta forma, assim você cria o arquivo post e deixa ele como se fosse uma categoria exemplo: www.site.com.br/post/primeira-materia/1 neste exemplo você precisa passar o ID do post para listar no site com o método GET.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#1
RewriteRule ^post\/([^\/]|.+[^\/]+)\/(\d+)\/?$ /posts.php?nome=$1&sid=$2
[QSA,L]
#0
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

Comment: Olá, neste exemplo ele vai receber 2 parâmetros, se quiser vou ter que alterar o `.htacess` e colocar o terceiro. É exatamente isso que não quero. Quero que qualquer arquivos, receba qualquer parâmetro de forma amigável. Desculpa  se não foi claro na pergunta.