# Como funciona o comando "RewriteRule"?

Tags: htaccess

Estou estudando a respeito do arquivo **.htaccess** e como ocorre o redirecionamento de paginas. Lendo a respeito de [URL amigáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75963/url-amig%C3%A1vel-utilizando-htaccess) me surgiu dúvidas em relação ao comando `RewriteRule`, mais especificamente ao seu funcionamento, elas vem logo abaixo.

## Dúvidas

1. Como funciona o comando `RewriteRule` e qual é a finalidade dele?
2. Que tipos de regras são aplicadas ao comando `RewriteRule`?

<sup>Se puderem dar exemplos práticos, vai facilitar o meu entendimento.</sup>