# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED - Por que o celular não consegue encontrar o caminho absoluto de arquivos através do localhost?

Tags: php, xampp, localhost

Estou desenvolvendo um site com `framework Bootstrap`

Durante o desenvolvimento, me deparei com o problema relacionado ao **caminho (path) das pastas,imagens, paginas** e etc.

Eu estava utilizando `include` para incluir a `header` e o `footer` no meu site, porém, eu sempre encontrava um erro no caminho, seja no include do header e footer, no caminho das imagens e/ou das pastas. Foi então que eu comecei a ler sobre caminho `relativo` e `absoluto`.

Para resolver o problema do caminho da header e footer, substituí meus includes por `file_get_contents`, onde eu salvo na variavel o endereço absoluto do meu site e depois apenas completo com o necessário. Nesse caso consigo imprimir a header e o footer em qualquer página do meu site.

Exemplo:

```
$a = file_get_contents("http://localhost/sites/nome_da_pasta/include/header.php");

echo $a;
```

Para resolver o problema do caminho das imagens, pastas e páginas, apenas inseri `http://localhost/sites/nome_da_pasta/nome_do_arquivo.php` dentro do `href` da tag `a`.

Antes dessas mudanças todas, eu conseguia acessar o site também atraves do celular, digitando no chrome do aparelho:

```
IPv4/caminho_do_site/index.php
```

Porém, eu tinha o problema do caminho relativo.

Até então os dois métodos citados acima, haviam resolvido meu problema no site utilizando navegador chrome no notebook. Porém, ao rodar o mesmo site no chrome do celular ou no navegador do mozila do notebook, aparecem erros:

- No celular aparece uma mensagem `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`
- No mozila apenas abre a página do localhost.

Segue o print do erro no celular:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minhas dúvidas são:

- Existe uma maneira correta de chamar o caminho absoluto das imagens, pastas, páginas e até mesmo footers e headers (sendo includes)?
- Existe uma maneira melhor de visualizar o site no celular? Sem ter a necessidade de usar o IPv4 (mesmo o site estando apenas no localhost)?
- Não entendo como o mesmo site, com as mesmas configurações e codificações roda no navegador chrome do notebook, mas tem dificuldade em rodar através do IPv4 no celular.
- Por que o "celular" não consegue encontrar o caminho das pastas/arquivos/imagens/paginas no localhost se o site (no notebook) consegue?

> **OBS: Gostaria de entender as perguntas que fiz acima, porém, minha maior necessidade é conseguir abrir o site no celular também.**

**Atualização:**

Baixei o navegador mozilla no celular para ver se o problema era apenas no chrome, o engraçado é que a página de login roda normalmente no celular, porém, quando digito email e senha, aparece a mensagem de erro, seguem 2 prints do teste no celular:

Tela Login:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois de digitar email e senha no celular (mantenha em mente que o site no desktop todas as páginas abrem normalmente):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: no lugar de `localhost` voce tem que usar o IP da maquina 'servidor', onde seu webserver esta rodando nos caminhos

Comment: Não é o IPv4? Estou um pouco perdida nessa área. Estou rodando localmente, dai antes eu conseguia ver pelo IPv4.

Comment: Você já tentou fazer o `include` e utilizar as imagens iniciando o caminho pela barra invertida ``\``? Desta forma, a URL ficará relativa ao *root* da aplicação. Por exemplo `include("/sites/silotransce/header.php")`. Você pode também configurar para o *root* seja a própria pasta *silotransce*, para bastar fazer `include("/header.php")`, o que facilita o *deploy* da aplicação.

Comment: Vou tentar dessa maneira, Anderson. Você acha então que se eu fizer desse modo, eu consigo rodar no celular também? Sera que é o "file_get_contents" que está dando problema?

Comment: Tentei e não deu certo, mas acho que descobri o problema e não estou sabendo arrumar. Percebe-se que no link que estou usando como caminho absoluto, tem o localhost. E no celular o que se usa para abrir é o número do IPv4. Tanto que a tela de login abre normalmente pq no caminho ainda ta o IP, mas qnd entra na pag_inicial vira localhost e então da o erro de conexão. Alguém sabe algum modo de colocar um IP padrão no lugar do localhost no link do href?

Comment: Não use `file_get_contents` para este propósito, use `include` ou `require`. Utilizar a minha dica acima resolverá seu problema. Se não funcionou, deve ter feito algo errado. Poste a sua estrutura de pastas e o seu código, por favor. Assim conseguiremos te ajudar melhor.

Comment: Olá, é realmente necessário que o `include` seja feito usando apenas **caminhos absolutos** ? Até porque, se for um *framework*, pode-se facilmente ter acesso a pasta `assets` ou `imagens` ou mesmo qualquer outro arquivo no servidor sem a necessidade de usar **caminhos absolutos**, usando apenas caminhos relativos por possuírem `paths` personalizados, há [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75963/url-amig%c3%a1vel-utilizando-htaccess/75970#75970) uma informação sobre os tipos de caminhos e alguns exemplos, apesar de quase ser um resumo.

Comment: Obrigada, depois de analisar as informações que me passaram, eu fiz como o Anderson havia dito anteriormente, porém, no meu caso não foi preciso usar a barra "/" antes do nome.php. Edilson, depois entendi que realmente não era necessário.

Comment: Certo, cria uma resposta com a solução usada. Se você resolveu seu problema utilizando `barra`, lembre-se que pode sempre usar o `DEFINE('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR)`, e quando precisar de escrever uma barra, é só digitar `DS`, e não terás de tentar adivinhar se é / ou \. Contudo recomendo criar fazer uso de `paths` personalizados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro: não use `file_get_contents`, ou use `include` ou `require`.

Os caminhos relativos e absolutos são sempre com base no que você definiu ao configurar o seu servidor. No Apache, você pode definir o caminho para o `DocumentRoot` no `apache2.conf`. Se você está usando o Xampp, encontre em `c:\XAMPP\apache\conf\httpd.conf`. Depois, muda a diretriz assim:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot C:/caminho/para/o/site
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory C:/caminho/para/o/site>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Reinicie o Apache. (fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157333/xampp-change-document-root)

O que você está fazendo aqui é mudar o caminho que o apache reconhece quando você acessa a porta 80 dessa máquina. Ou seja, o localhost. Agora, pelo que vi na sua pergunta, você configurou vários sites em uma mesma pasta. O correto seria criar um `VirtualHost` pra cada site que você tiver aí, ou colocar eles em portas diferentes, talvez. De qualquer forma, já fica fora do escopo.

O problema que você estava tendo com o `include` era por que você estava tentando usar um caminho absoluto que começava antes da pasta do próprio site. Então ele estava procurando `header.php` dentro da raíz que está lá no Apache, que provavelmente contém a pasta `site`.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa ir no `PHP.ini` e autorizar o `include` usando HTTP.

Procure no `php.ini` por `allow_url_include` e se estiver `off` troque para `on`, se estiver `0` troque para `1`.

Comment: Eu li que autorizando o include em allow_url_include não é uma coisa boa a se fazer, pois posso ter vários problemas com isso no futuro.