# O que faz essa regex htaccess?

Tags: regex, htaccess

Tenho essa regex:

```
RewriteRule ^www\/login\/?$ login/ [L,NC,R]
```

O que ela faz?

Comment: Reescreve o caminho `www/login/` para `login/`.

Comment: @UzmkArtanis duplicata é forçar a barra, mas com certeza é uma ótima **Relacionada**.

Comment: As flags estão muito bem explicadas lá. Eu somente estou tentando ajudar a direcionar para um único local. Mas sim, como relacionada é bom @KaduAmaral

Comment: Aqui tem outra relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75963/url-amig%C3%A1vel-utilizando-htaccess

Answer (score 7):

Essa é um regra de reescrita que está dizendo que a URL iniciada com www/login precedido de / (**barra**) ou não, redirecione para login/. As *flags* [L,NC,R] significam:

O **[L]** é *last*, ou seja, em uma lista de condições, não serão lidas as condições abaixo da que estiver com esta flag.

O **[R]** é *redirect*, isso comanda o navegador a fazer o redirecionamento. É preciso colocar a URL completa.

O **[NC]** é *no-case*, apenas faz com que as comparações sejam feitas no modo case-insensitive, ou seja, sem diferenciar maiúsculas de minúsculas.

Recomendo a leitura da documentação do Apache [aqui](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html) e também dessa pergunta **relacionada** para mais informações: [URL amigável, como fazer funcionar com HTACCESS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/53973/url-amig%C3%A1vel-como-fazer-funcionar-com-htaccess).

Comment: obrigado,  pela melhoria @UzmkArtanis

Comment: Não é bem "qualquer coisa iniciada" apenas a url que tiver `www/login/`, `www/login`, se fosse "qualquer coisa" funcionaria para url `www/login/usuario/13`

Comment: "A url que tiver" ficou igual a "Qualquer coisa iniciada" vago de explicação, porque não especifica que é após o domínio que deve conter www/login, uma vez que vem depois do operador ^. De qualquer forma tentei melhorar para ficar mais claro seguindo a dica do amigo @Guilherme.