# Como escrever esta url no .htaccess para obter uma url amigável?

Tags: htaccess

Preciso escrever uma instrução no `.htaccess` para obter esta url num formato amigável. Esta é ela:

***http://dent.axitech.com.br/admin/views/home.php***

... preciso que se transforme em:

***http://dent.axitech.com.br/admin/home***

Não entende nada de .htaccess

Obrigado

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/53973/url-amig%C3%A1vel-como-fazer-funcionar-com-htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sou especialista em PHP, mas acho que isso resolve.

Coloque no seu `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: O link que o @jbueno postou tem muito mais detalhes, não tinha visto o comentário antes de responder.

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com a URL que você quer, você poderia fazer dessa forma:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ views/$1.php

</IfModule>
```

Onde você teria que colocar o arquivo **.htaccess** na pasta admin assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]