# Como utilizar na URL o título de um produto?

Tags: php, url

Por exemplo eu tenho uma página onde listo os produtos : `http://exemplo.com/produtos.php` e ao clicar em algum dos produtos listados a URL fica `http://exemplo.com/produtos.php?id=2`.

Supondo que o produto de `id=2` possua um título `Relógio Patek Philippe 1928`, como alterar a URL para que ao invés de `http://exemplo.com/produtos.php?id=2` fique `http://exemplo.com/produtos/Relógio-Patek-Philippe-1928` como acontece aqui no SOpt ?

Comment: Nesse link tem uma explicação de como fazer http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/53973/url-amig%C3%A1vel-como-fazer-funcionar-com-htaccess

Comment: massa num tinha visto vou dar uma olhada ver se atende...vlw man.

Comment: primeiro teria que fazer um slug do nome do produto: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335215/what-is-a-slug , depois adiciona uma coluna a essa tabela (de produto) `slug` e coloca lá... E depois em vez de procurar (SELECT, SQL) por onde o `id=2` (ex) procura por onde `slug=Relógio-Patek-Philippe-1928`. Nota que desta maneira tens de garantir que os slugs são também unicos