# Como mudar a página inicial do diretório através do .htaccess?

Tags: htaccess

Possuo um site que quando acessado, você é redirecionado para a página `index.php`, mas na verdade eu quero que ele seja redirecionado para a página `inicio.html`. Como eu consigo mudar isso?

Comment: Você quer que a p[agina inicial seja o arquivo `inicio.html`, ou você quer reescrever a URL `http://site/inicio.html` para que acesse do lado do servidor como `index.php` e ainda sim o usuário irá ver `inicio.html`? Poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: Desculpe-me se não fui claro. Eu queria que quando acessar o meu site, a pessoa seja redirecionada para inicio.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por padrão, quando o navegador faz a requisição, é devolvido o arquivo `index.html` do site requisitado. Nesse caso, pensando que você quer uma resposta que resolva o problema, nesse escopo especificamente, utilize no arquivo `.htaccess`:

```
DirectoryIndex inicio.html
```

Considerando que o seu arquivo está na raiz, juntamente com o arquivo de configuração do Apache, o `.htaccess`, você está, dizendo que o índice do diretório se chamará `inicio.html`, e ele deve ser carregado invés do `index.php`.

Se você deseja mudar, a configuração geral do Apache, para **sempre** procurar por `inicio.html`, ao invés do padrão, `index.html`, é necessário que você altere as configurações do arquivo `httpd.conf`. Segue a mesma linha de código:

```
DirectoryIndex inicio.html
```

Entretanto, se você quer utilizar de URLs amigáveis, aconselho a leitura da seguinte [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53973/66203) que já cobre, bem o assunto, assim como a procura de [perguntas relacionadas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=URL+amig%C3%A1vel+%5B.htaccess%5D).

Se você estiver procurando por redirecionamento 301 e 302, e não mudar a "página inicial" do `.htacess`, por favor, leia essa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/247511/66203).

Comment: Talvez seja isso que respondeu, talvez não, [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/247503/como-mudar-a-p%c3%a1gina-inicial-do-diret%c3%b3rio-atrav%c3%a9s-do-htaccess#comment507355_247503)

Answer (score 1):

> Eu queria que quando acessar o meu site, a pessoa seja redirecionada para inicio.html. - [Robson](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/247503/como-mudar-a-p%C3%A1gina-inicial-do-diret%C3%B3rio-atrav%C3%A9s-do-htaccess/247511#comment507357_247503)

Se entendi, você quer redirecionar mesmo, ao acessar algo como `http://meusite.com` ele irá direcionar para `http://meusite.com/inicio.html`.

### 301 vs 302

Você tem duas opções, o redirecionamento 301, que é o redirecionamento permanente:

```
Redirect 301 / http://meusite.com/inicio.html
```

Redirecionamento temporário:

```
Redirect 302 / http://meusite.com/inicio.html
```

O redirecionamento permanente vai fazer o navegador do usuário passar a desconsiderar o `/` assim como os buscadores também não irão indexar o `/`, pois ele considera ambos a mesma URL, sendo que `inicio.html` é o novo endereço, já no 302 é temporário, ambas URLs ainda existem, mas técnicamente `/` estará temporariamente indisponível e por isto estará apontando para o `inicio.html`, creio que você queira o 301.

---

Note que arquivos com extensão `.html` por padrão não irão executar scripts `.php` "embarcados" dentro dele, se deseja que o `inicio.html` seja um `php`, mas com extensão `.html`, além do redirecionamento, você pode usar o *mod_rewrite* no seu `.htaccess`, assim:

```
#direciona / ou index.php (que estejam na raiz) para inicio.html
Redirect 301 / http://meusite.com/inicio.html
Redirect 301 /index.php http://meusite.com/inicio.html

#Ativa o Rewrite
RewriteEngine On

#Ao acessar http://meusite.com/inicio.html será exibido o conteudo index.php
#mas você poderá escrever conteudos no `.php`
RewriteRule ^inicio\.html$ index.php [L]
```

Agora se você quer que todos scripts tenham a extensão `.html` na URL, mas você ainda sim use os `.php` **do lado do servidor**, você pode usar assim:

```
#direciona / ou index.php (que estejam na raiz) para inicio.html
Redirect 301 / http://meusite.com/inicio.html
Redirect 301 /index.php http://meusite.com/inicio.html

#Ativa o Rewrite
RewriteEngine On

#qualquer url que tiver a extesão `.html` irá acessar um .php, mas o usuário irá ver como .html
RewriteRule (^|/)([^/]+)\.html$ $2.php [L]
```

Por exemplo se acessar isto `http://meusite.com/foo.html` no lado do servidor será executado `foo.php`, mas o usuário irá ver na url `foo.html`, assim você poderá escrever páginas dinâmicas em PHP e mostrar a extensão `.html`.

Answer (score 0):

Se você estiver utilizando Apache, abra o arquivo httpd.conf e altere a linha `DirectoryIndex` para:

```
DirectoryIndex  inicio.html index.html index.htm
```

Desta forma, o arquivo padrão que o Apache irá buscar será `inicio.html`.
Se este arquivo não existir, então ele irá procurar por um arquivo chamado `index.html` (o padrão), e assim por diante.
Caso não encontre nenhum arquivo, irá listar o conteúdo do diretório caso isso seja permitido.

Alternativamente, você pode colocar a mesma diretiva no arquivo `.htaccess`, conforme explicado em outra resposta.
A diferença é que alterando o arquivo, sua configuração é válida para o "escopo" do arquivo. Geralmente somente o seu domínio ou diretório.
Alterando no Apache, a configuração é válida para todos os domínios.
A alteração no arquivo `.htaccess` sempre irá sobrescrever a configuração do Apache.