# URL amigável recebendo valor p/ PHP

Tags: php, htaccess, apache, url, url-rewrite

Minha dúvida se encontra nessa *URL*:

`site.com/embed.php?id=a48sa4d2a3s4d65a1s5d6a1sd56`

Recebo esse valor pelo `$_GET['id']`.

Como posso transformar em uma *URL* bonita e organizada? Exemplo:

`site.com/embed/a48sa4d2a3s4d65a1s5d6a1sd56`

Quero remover esse parâmetro `?id=`.

Já consegui remover o `.php` com `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adicione isto no seu `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^embed\/([0-9A-z_-]+)$ embed.php?id=$1 [QSA,L,NC]

</IfModule>
```

Caso já tenha este bloco de código no seu `.htaccess`, basta copiar a linha da regra.

> Fonte (exemplo): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/86900/45810