# Como criar url's amigáveis com .htaccess apontando para um caminho diferente de onde está o arquivo referenciado?

Tags: php, htaccess, url

Tenho uma dúvida referente a deixar as URL amigáveis para um site, creio que o título não está muito claro, mas seria o seguinte:

Estou fazendo uma manutenção em um site antigo em PHP, ele foi escrito de maneira com que as estruturas da página (header, menu lateral, conteúdo e rodapé) fossem divididas em arquivos separados. Então todas as páginas possuem um link para os outros arquivos de estrutura usando o **include** do PHP.

Acontece que todas as páginas foram criadas na raiz do site, ou seja, são mais 100 páginas que estão "jogadas" e eu gostaria de organizá-las melhor criando categorias, no caso de produtos. **O problema é que eu queria fazer isso apenas reescrevendo a URL pelo htaccess, ainda assim mantendo as páginas na raiz pois dessa forma todos os arquivos e links externos já estão referenciados**, ou seja, se eu criar subpastas eu perderia por exemplo as referências de scripts e estilos externos.

---

**TL;DR**

Gostaria de fazer algo como "categoria/produto/subproduto" alterando apenas a URL, sem necessariamente criar subpastas para isso. Senão eu perco as referências de arquivos externos (pois não compensa pra mim alterar um por um pois são muitos!)

Teria alguma solução para contornar esse problema?

Obrigado!

Comment: Leandro, achilo que entendi e editei o título, se achar que não ficou bom você pode reverter a edição.

Comment: Talvez esta pergunta ajude. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/53973/url-amig%C3%A1vel-como-fazer-funcionar-com-htaccess

Comment: Obrigado pessoal! Problema resolvido

Comment: Leandro, se quiser vc pode deixar uma resposta com a solução encontrada, para servir de referência a outras pessoas que chegarem a esta página.

Comment: Ok @gustavox, obrigado pelas dicas

Answer (score -2, accepted):

O problema foi resolvido utilizando a seguinte tag no header da minha página:

```
<base href="/">
```

Desse modo, como todos links para arquivos externos eram a partir do index, agora é acrescentado uma "/" que significa agora que os links são relativos a raiz (independente de subdiretórios).

Obs: Tem outra alternativa que é o comando `RewriteBase` do arquivo .htaccess, mas por algum motivo não consegui, apenas com a tag `<base>` mesmo.